# Is it possible to change the cell.value in a WinFormCore DataGridViewCell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2019, datagridviewcellstyle

EDIT:

As  György Kőszeg commented, the way to fi my problem ws to override the ToString() value on my Station class, now its returning the desired value

I am populating a DataGridView with a list.

My List contains strings, datetime and classes.

the problem is the Column with the class. it is just showing as the object name. so cell content is: OperatingLog.Model.Station.
(datatable picture)
[Data table showing my the Test column showing entire object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzqsE.png)

What i would want instead is to show a value from the object. lets say OperatingLog.Model.Station.ExternalId. However when i try to change the cell value (picture of code)

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6pqx.png)

i get this error saying that i cant convert the object to string.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGvwR.png)

i just want to add a "label" or something, not change the object.

Only help i found on internet is to make a model with all the fields in strings instead of classes.
[Model example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsBSY.png)

however i do not like this approach since the classes can have a lot of properties where i need the data but dont want to show it all.

Comment: You can override the `ToString` of the class to be displayed.

Comment: Thank you so much man ! i figured it out and your suggestions is exactly what i needed

Comment: The cell alone can't be made invisible. The Visible property will only tell you if either the row or the column are invisible.

Comment: TaW i get why it confused you in the title. i am going to change it. i am not looking for ways to change visible state. but the "visible value" :)